# How do I prevent murder?

Tags: dishonored

I'm currently trying to kill as few people as possible in Dishonored. I learned the hard way that throwing unconscious people into the water instantly kills them, so I'm not doing that anymore. I assumed this was the only thing I couldn't do (short of shooting or stabbing them) that would kill an unconscious person.

However, while lazily hiding unconscious bodies, I threw someone down a staircase, assuming they'd be fine, but when I checked on them, they weren't snoring. What *can't* I do to unconscious people if I want to keep them alive? That is, what all kills them besides the obvious shooting or stabbing them?

Comment: I can only imagine what would happen if this got migrated to legal.se with the name Dishonored removed ... oh the hilarity.

Comment: It's tag:[tag:murder] all over again :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The critical area for an unconscious body is their head.

- Moving them around and having their head hit things will kill them.
- Dropping heavy things on their head also kills them (whale oil canisters can do this).
- Dropping them some distance will also kill them.
- Drowning with their head submerged will kill them.
- Rats will go after unconscious bodies and eat them.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll have to be careful, ugh.

Comment: Safe knockouts can be very time consuming.  If you accidentally acquire more chaos than normal, random rat swarms start showing up and end up killing more unconscious guys on the ground.  As odd as it sounds, I try to leave dead bodies on tables and furniture if the whole area is secure, but it wastes a lot of time messing with bodies.

Comment: Are you sure rats go for unconscious people? I thought they just ate the dead?

Comment: Google for "dishonored rats eat unconscious".  There are people asking whether rats eating unconscious people counts against you, so yeah, it happens and people want to know if it counts against you (yes it does).  It's been years I played this, but moving bodies into dumpster and high ground was such an annoying part that I remember doing this all the time.